# Is there any way to hide a div's contents but not the div itself?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover

So here's what Im looking to do in its most simplified form. I want to have a box appear on the page and when you hover over it, it's contents are visible, otherwise they are hidden. So for example let's say we have this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#box {
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>

<div id="box">
    <img src="smileyface.png" />
</div>
```

Most of the time, the image is hidden and this looks like a red box, but when the div is hovered over the image appears. Is there any way to do this with CSS and not javascript. I know with javascript we could just remove the element and add it back in as we go, but I just want to show it and hide it. Thoughts?

****Must be IE 8 compliant because I'm a glutton for punishment.****

Comment: Why is your CSS in a script block?

Comment: @j08691 is right. You should put your CSS between <style type="text/css"> [...] </style>

Comment: @j08691 Whoops! I never use inline CSS so I was just being stupid right there.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite easy. Just change the display property of the image when the `#box` is hovered

```
#box > img {
  display: none;
}

#box:hover > img {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Cool, but let's say there's more than just an image inside the div. What if there was a heading, a paragraph, and an image?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more suitable to use visibility:hidden; here, so that the space is preserved?

Comment: Either set a rule for each of them or put them in a wrapper div.

Comment: @StefanSurkamp That is possible as well, but I didn't show that in this case as he already had `#box` defined to have a fixed size.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *:hover* on any tag you'd like to:

```
#box {
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

#box:hover {
    background-image: src('smileyface.png');
}
```

Comment: PS: IE correctly interprets pseudo-classes (as :hover) since version 7.